# How does a symmetric force affect a symmetric object?

Tags: forces, symmetry

Let's say we have a symmetric needle, and it's standing vertically. Then we apply a symmetric force F from above. What happens as we gradually increase F? Does the needle start to shrink in length? Will the length eventually approach zero? Forgive me if I couldn't be more precise, but I think you get the idea.

How accurately can this experiment be done in real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your question is getting at, I think, is the phenomenon of [buckling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling). If you push the needle enough it will not want to compress symmetrically. It will cost less energy to bend in a certain direction. So even though you are pushing perfectly symmetrically it will want to be in an asymmetric configuration.

The overall physics is still symmetric since the set of all possible buckled directions is symmetric. This is an example of something called [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking), which appears in a lot of branches of physics.

Comment: Thank you. According to what you implied, the laws governing this situation are not deterministic?

Comment: Which buckled state it goes into is not deterministic. The choice will depend on small perturbations.